# Query con clases abstractas en quarkus

Tags: typescript, graphql, quarkus

estoy haciendo un microservicio graphql con quarkus y queria ver si hay manera de mandar traer en una sola query los detalles de las subclases de una clase en particular.

controlador:

```
@Query
@Description("Retrieves all templates")
public List<SurveyTemplate> getTemplates() {
    return templateService.getTemplates();
}
```

SurveyTemplate:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
@Getter
public class SurveyTemplate   implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long surveyTemplateId;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Section> sections;
}
```

Section:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
@Getter
public class Section  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long sectionId;
    @Description("The section name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Question.class)
    private List<? extends Question> questions;
}
```

### Intentos

De momento estoy usando source en mi controlador para obtener una maneras de obtener los datos

```
@Query
public boolean isDateQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    return question instanceof DateQuestion;
}

@Query
public boolean isOpenQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    return question instanceof OpenQuestion;
}

@Query
public boolean isMultipleOptionQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    return question instanceof MultipleOptionQuestion;
}

@Query
public DateQuestion getDateQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    if (isDateQuestion(question)) {
        return (DateQuestion) question;
    }
    return null;
}

@Query
public OpenQuestion getOpenQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    if (isOpenQuestion(question)) {
        return (OpenQuestion) question;
    }
    return null;
}

@Query
public MultipleOptionQuestion getMultipleOptionQuestion(@Source Question question) {
    if (isMultipleOptionQuestion(question)) {
        return (MultipleOptionQuestion) question;
    }
    return null;
}

@Query
public String getQuestionType(@Source Question question) {
    if (isDateQuestion(question)) {
        return "DateQuestion";
    } else {
        if (isOpenQuestion(question)) {
            return "OpenQuestion";
        } else {
            return "MultipleOptionQuestion";
        }
    }
}
```

y hago mi consulta de esta manera:

```
{
      sayHello
      templates {
        surveyTemplateId
        sections {
          sectionId
          name
          questions {
            statement
            required
            questionId
            type: questionType
            openQuestion {
              answer
            }
            dateQuestion {
              date
            }
            multipleOptionQuestion {
              answerOptions
              answerIdx
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

pero la entidad en mi frontend queda diferente

```
export class Question {
  statement: string = "";
  type: string = "";
  required: boolean = false;

  openQuestion: OpenQuestion | null = null;
  dateQuestion: DateQuestion | null = null;
  multipleOptionQuestion: MultipleOptionQuestion | null = null;
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo mejorar el codigo de preferencia para que puedda usar subclases?